# How to pass a url to a JavaScript function as a parameter?

Tags: php, javascript

I just want to pass the base url to a javaScript  function. Function call is like as follows

```
<img src="assets/images/c_arow_rite.jpg" onClick="nextMonth('.$bs_url.')"/>
```

It showing an error in the Error Console like

```
Error: SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal
Source File: `http://mywebsite/rand/`
Line: 1, Column: 15
Source Code:
nextMonth(http%3A%2F%2F192.168.1.254%2Frand%2F)
```

Comment: try to pass the URL within double quotes as a string.

Comment: Don't pass it at all? `location.href`, `location.host`, `location.pathname`, `location.protocol`, `location.port`... there's a lot of info already available to you. If it's not the current url, then `'quote the url'`

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
<img src="assets/images/c_arow_rite.jpg" onClick="nextMonth('.$bs_url.')"/>
```

Should be written as:

```
<img src="assets/images/c_arow_rite.jpg" onClick="nextMonth(\''.$bs_url.'\')"/>
```

to add string delimiters that don't muck up the double quotes of the HTML, and are escaped in your php script. I think I'm right in assuming this is actually part of a statement like:

```
echo '<img src="assets/images/c_arow_rite.jpg" onClick="nextMonth(\''.$bs_url.'\')"/>';
```

In which case, adding escaped single quotes is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do just like this:

`<img src="assets/images/c_arow_rite.jpg" onClick="nextMonth($bs_url)"/>`

Comment: only if the php quotes are " or heredoc afaik, not '

Comment: @JanusTroelsen, Right now what is the quote?